# Vuetify v-treeview get node that was last clicked on

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

What is the easiest way to retrieve the (id of the) node that was just clicked on in a `<v-treeview>`? There is the `update:open` event that emits an array of all open nodes. I could temporarily store the whole array and compare a new version with the old one to see which element was added or removed. But this seems to be a bit cumbersome, right? I want to use the id of the node to dynamically reload the children of the children of the node from the backend, so that the user has the feeling that the data is already in the frontend. Maybe it is possible to emit in the `update:open` event not the whole array, but only the current node, somehow like this: `@update:open="onExpand(item)"`? (This throws the error `Property or method "item" is not defined`.)

Comment: include the code inside the <vtreeview>

Answer (score 1):

You could use `VTreeView`'s [`label` slot](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-treeview/#slots), which passes the `item` itself in its slot props. In that slot, you could render a `span` with a `click` handler that also includes the item:

```html
<template>
  <v-treeview :items="items">
    <template #label="{ item }">
      <span @click="onItemClick(item)">{{item.name}}</span>
    </template>
  </v-treeview>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    onItemClick(item) {
      console.log(item.id)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Upvoted as this is a good work around. But do keep in mind that the click event will only be triggered when you click the label of a treeview's node, and *not* when you clicked the arrows on the left. https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-morning-nqirn?file=/src/components/Playground.vue

Comment: I ended up using the load-children prop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `update:active` with the `return-object` prop. It will return the full object instead of the node id.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-treeview/#props